# Hacer que una imagen sea circular en Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Qué tal, estoy trabajando con un proyecto en Xcode y quiero saber como cambiar el estilo de una imagen para que se muestre circular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te refieres a conseguir algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que necesitas es el siguiente código:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
```